# Allow textarea re-size in lower-left corner

Tags: html, css

Can I get the small re-size widget that appears in the lower right of text areas (on modern browsers) to appear on the lower left?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS3 adds a "resize" property that allows you to control whether the textarea is resizable. But as far as I can tell, there's no property that specifies where the handle is. If you want that level of control, you'll have to implement the widget yourself with Javascript (similar to the way the jQuery Dialog widget adds a resize handle to the DIV it creates).

Comment: Unfortunate, perhaps we will have to rethink our layout.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You can do that by setting writing direction to right-to-left. This implies that text is aligned to the right by default, but this can easily be overridden:

```
textarea { resize: both; direction: rtl; text-align: left; }
```

There are other side effects that you cannot override. The vertical scroll bar will appear on the left. The cursor will appear at the left at times (after typing in a directionally neutral character), even characters will appear on the right when typing only left-to-right characters intermixed with neutral characters – though directionally neutral characters first appear at the left (test with typing “abc (1) x” to see what I mean).

So it comes with features that are oddities when typing left-to-right text, and it’s better to look for a different approach to the original problem (whatever it was that made you want to put the resize handle in the lower left corner).

Answer (score -1):

That's not meant to be done, because then the standard of textareas would be very inconsistent and that's what the W3C tries to avoid. The internet should be consistent in some things and the resizing widget of the html textarea element will most likely always be on the right. One thing you can do is use jQuery or other JavaScript techniques to add a resizing widget in the bottom left and cover the one in the bottom right.